# My keyboard shift & ctrl keys are flickering on and off Win 10, Recent after auto update

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Here's an example of typing numbers 1 and 2 with both <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys:

> ```
> 11111!1!!!11!!11111!11!!11!!!!!!!!1!1
>
> @22222@@2@@@2@
>
> !!!1!11!11111!11
>
> 22@2@@@2@@2@@2@@@@@2@@@@@222@
> ```

While holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys, both sides doing it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> also acting up.

Windows 10 froze during an update yesterday at 27% and backing out of it. Is this a malware issue?

Using Dell Desktop.

Comment: It is more likely that the freeze is *the result* of a problem, *not the cause*. It might be a hardware issue. But this is speculation. You can try a different keyboard to see if it happens there too. If you can rule out hardware, I would try going back to an earlier restore point, trying to update the drivers, stuff like that. In all cases, its most likely not malware.

Comment: this was the answer. I had tried BIOS and restores etc. and cleaning out the lint of the keys but it's looking like the circuits were frying or the drivers for that particular keyboard only weren't recognized. !!!!!!@@@@ = happiness. Thanks LP!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I've posted this as an answer you you can mark this question as solved, indicating that you no longer need help. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that the freeze is the result of a problem, not the cause. It might be a hardware issue. But this is speculation. You can try a different keyboard to see if it happens there too.

If you can rule out hardware, I would try going back to an earlier restore point, trying to update the drivers, stuff like that. In all cases, its most likely not malware.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of keyboard is it? USB, Bluetooth? I would suggest trying the keyboard on a different PC and trying a working keyboard on your system.

Edit: I just saw, it was already answered, well I leave this answer anyway in case it will be helpful for other users.